# C++: check if an address is being referred to

Tags: c++, pointers

Is there a way in C++ to check if a memory address is being referred to by any pointer?

Comment: What do you mean by a memory address? An object will take up a range of addresses, the pointer will only point to the beginning. Are you wanting to say `I have this chunk of memory addresses and want to know whether any objects in the system are in it`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not at all.

(Unless you do the tracking yourself obviously.)

Comment: To the "do the tracking yourself", may be it is not feasible, or better "not with plan pointers".

Although you can replace new/delete to see what is allocated, until it is possible to do pointer assignment and arithmetics the "tracking" risk to be unsuccessful (since there are operation that can bypass it)

It is possible (in C-like way) to implement an Hans Bohem algorithm, over the plain addresses but it is not possible to properly destroy objects.

The C++ way should require a garbage collectable pointer class that cooperate with a garbage collected new (hand has a disabled delete)

Answer (score 2):

That would mean C++ had a garbage collector or equivalent, which it doesn't. In other words, no.

You can utilize smart (and especially shared for this use case) pointers to manage your memory for you.

Comment: Yes... I understand smart pointer is an option... my project is a large one consisting of 1000s of files... replacing all the pointers with smart counter parts is simply implausible... Just wanted to check if we have any other method to do this... Thx!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Just think about pointer arithmetics: from a given memory location you can increment your way and reach different locations. This is used to move across arrays: from

```
int * a = &array[0];
```

nobody knows if you will do ++a, a+3, or whatever. And you can, starting from array[0], go outside of the bounds of the array (which is not bounded, in effect :-) ).

This is deeply ingrained in C and C++ inherited it, but C++ has developed a series of idiomatic styles which try to reduce to the minimum the need to go to the raw pointer level. You can read about smart pointers (which keep count of who is referring to a given resource and delete it when the count goes to zero). Instead of arrays in many instances you can use std::vector which gives you many benefits without having to care for the risk of going one step beyond the end of the array.

Comment: This is not the true reason why. A C compiler could put together the detailed information about each object and pass that to the run time, so that it would  be possible to compute the set of all objects that are reachable. You would know where every pointer is hiding and then you could check them all to see whether they point at a given address. That could be true for out-of-bounds pointers also. If we can traverse all data and reach this variable 'a' and know that it is a pointer, we can compare it to a given address. But, alas, we don't have that info.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your reasoning: suppose that you have a pointer and that you dynamically compute an offset and point the pointer to the new location. Sure, this will be in the space allocated by the system to your process, but how can you know without setting up somewhere else a book keeping machinery (essentially a garbage collector)? This is possible but is very different from the C way (raw pointer and manual memory management) and from the C++ way (smart pointers, RAII, standard libray containers).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own smart pointer, dynamic memory allocation or garbage collector before you can do this.

Comment: You don't need to _implement it yourself_, as there are smart pointers in stdlib. Don't reinvent the wheel, unless your point is to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: OK, but not sure if you can then ask them for if any pointer is  referring to them.

Comment: So what, your smart pointers will create big table for every addressable byte and store pointer counter for every addressable byte? I don't think so. To check whether address is pointed to by something and how much that "somethings" are there, you will have to access smart pointer object. Keeping track of pointers pointing at given byte without checking it in smart pointer would be too big overhead to be useful. In general, you will just leave memory management to smart pointers and use them to control memory - no need to store counter outside of them.

Answer (score 0):

No. Not really. But...

---

The [Boehm Garbage Collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) quite successfully manages to do so by being pessimistic, that is considering that anything that looks like a memory address *is* a memory address (and not a random integer or succession of bitfields that just happen to look so). Being pessimistic means that some data is collected much later than it could have been, but this is not too important for a Garbage Collector (and much better than collecting too soon!).

---

In C++11, a number of [low-level facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) have been introduced to ease the creation of garbage collectors:

- `declare_reachable`: declares that an object can not be recycled
- `undeclare_reachable`: declares that an object can be recycled
- `declare_no_pointers`: declares that a memory area does not contain traceable pointers
- `undeclare_no_pointers`: cancels the effect of `std::declare_no_pointers`
- `pointer_safety`: lists pointer safety models
- `get_pointer_safety`: returns the current pointer safety model

The `declare_no_pointers` is a hint that an object only contains integers/bitfields/whatever and no pointers, so that when scanning the Garbage Collector may be more accurate. This knowledge may be leveraged in your case.

---

However, all of this fall prey to *packing tricks*. For example, it is common to exploit the fact that 64 bits pointers have way too many bits and use a few of them to store flags within the pointer. Or on the contrary to exploit the `double` `NaN` payload to store a pointer or integer value. Obviously this does not sit well with scanning memory looking for pointers as the values scanned do not correspond to real addresses.

Those tricks are heavily used in Clang/LLVM or Javascript engines (V8, SpiderMonkey, ...) for example, and in general in pieces of software that really care for memory footprint and speed.

---

So, in general, no C and C++ are too *loose* with memory to accurately being able to know that. Even `std::shared_ptr` is no more than a *convention* and one could accidentally store the *raw* pointer elsewhere.

In practice though, there are solutions for most of the problems you may have. Either using the type system and a few conventions or using Boehm's scan (which should be pretty rare...). However this requires a more elaborated question.